# changing font color and size has no effect in CKEditor Drupal

Tags: drupal, ckeditor

I am a beginner of Drupal. I found it had no effect on changing text color and size in CKEditor. After I changed the text color of a web page from the default black color to red and saved it in CKEditor, nothing happended actually in the page after reloaded it. The same problem also applied to the font size. I don't know what I am missing in the configuration. My Druapl version is 7 and the CKEditor is 7x-1.15. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Do you override size and color in your CSS? Like "content p{size: 12px;}" or "article p{color: black;"...

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. I'll try to change the size and color in CSS, but I am just starting to learn it in Drupal. Why CkEditor won't change the text size and color? Is it a bug?

Comment: Normally, CKEditor changes well size and color without problem. But you seem to have something else that avoids CKEditor to make its changes. Maybe a CSS property that overrides the style of your content. I don't know if you customize your theme a lot? Did you write a lot of CSS or not at all?

Comment: Your Text Format Filters are likely stripping out the inline CSS that CKEditor put in.  See https://www.drupal.org/node/213156

Comment: This is just a test webpage. I am not using CSS in it. I am not clear how to configure the Text Format Filters to avoid stripping out the inline CSS that CKEditor put in. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi all, the problem is solved after I unchecked the "Limited allowed HTML tags" option in "Filtered HTML". Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: Thanks @Bigfanx for posting this question and the solution you found out. For anyone facing the same, Choose the "Configure" option  under  Administration » Configuration » Content authoring » Text formats, for the right Text profile and configure there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the very same problem with BUEditor yesterday. My CSS classes were being stripped and hence no colour. Then I realised I had to use Full HTML instead.

Answer (score 0):

Easy to fix just go to the module and search for Filter and edit the confutation configuration as below
Enable the check box to the following list and uncheck the others (checkbox )

1. Authenticated user
2. Administrator
3. Convert line breaks into HTML
4. Convert URLs into links
5. Correct faulty and chopped off HTML

Comment: This is a little difficult to follow. Consider re-editing your answer to allow for easier reading.

Comment: @Jeff check the answer again